# Can you describe a span of two vectors as a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra, plane-geometry

Let us assume that we have a plane H given by:

$$ H=\lbrace\lambda\left\lbrack1,-1,0\right\rbrack^{^{^T}}+\alpha\left\lbrack0,-1,1\right\rbrack^{^{^T}}\mid\alpha,\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\rbrace $$

Is there a way to describe this plane as:

$$ Ax+By+Cy+D=0 $$

If so, what would be the most effective way of finding this plane?
And if not, why is this not possible?

Comment: Presumably you meant to add the two vectors, not separate by a comma. Also, what ambient space are you in?

Comment: Yes you are correct - will edit

Comment: The ambient would be in R^3.

Comment: You can take the cross product of the two vectors to get a normal to the plane, whose coordinates will give you $A,B,C$, and then $D=0$.

Comment: Understood. It makes sense. Please answer the question so I can mark it as solved. Thank you :)

Comment: The tow vectors needs to be linearly independent. Another way is to find a third vector $v_3$ such that $v_3$ is perpendicular to both of the above vectors, then the plane (in this case subspace too) is given by $v_3^T (x,y,z)^T = 0$ which is the form you are looking for.

Comment: @copper.hat In $\mathbb{R}^3$, the cross product is the usual way of finding a vector perpendicular to two linearly independent vectors.

Comment: @aschepler It might help the OP to have a more geometric perspective.

Comment: Please, don't use $\alpha$ and $\lambda$ together, it hurts my eyes.

Comment: @AndrésMartínez The Greek for almond is αμύγδαλο.

Comment: @copper.hat and the english for almond is almond, but nobody names two variables $a$ and $l$ together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porting my comment to an answer per request: since the vectors $[1,-1,0]^T$ and $[0,-1,1]^T$ are linearly independent in $\mathbb{R}^3$, you can compute their cross product to obtain the vector $[-1,-1,-1]^T$ which is normal to the plane spanned by the two vectors. A vector $[x,y,z]^T$ is in this plane if and only if
$$[-1,-1,-1]\cdot[x,y,z]^T=-x-y-z=0$$
So you can take $A=B=C=-1$ and $D=0$ in the equation (where $Cy$ should be $Cz$).